# remoteproc based inter-core communication

Tags: arm, ipc, multicore

I am trying investigate various inter-core communication mechanism on my Dual core Arm-Cortex Processor. One of the core is running a baremetal application and another one is running Linux operating system. I just came across the remoteproc framework ( rpmsg) and I could not find much information online. Only information i found was http://lwn.net/Articles/489009/ which is quite less to get started. Is there any one who could help me with this?

Comment: do you need a framework to communicate with a dsp? remoteproc looks like for such purpose.

Comment: No i have just a baremetal application doing just a real time task on one core and the other core is running linux. I need to communicate some information from the Real time task to the a process running linux on the other. I think the framework can be used for this purpose too.

Comment: You can use the *bus locking* instructions like `ldrex` and `strex` to implement [tag:lockfree] IPC algorithms, if both CPUs support this.  Possibly you can find a framework like this.  If both CPUs do not support this, then you need some other hardware mechanism that is particular to the **SOC**; not all **Cortex** chips support `strex` and `ldrex`, so we need to know a little more.

Comment: Hi Artless Noise, Could you suggest some IPC algorithms or Frameworks which i should look into. I am actually trying to implement a IPC between 2 cores running completely different programs. One is running linux and another is running a bare metal application. I saw this Remoteproc(rpmsg)  based  communication is used widely in a Asymmetric Multiprocessing set up widely. But there not much papers explaining the same and also how the performance of the same will be.

Comment: @artlessnoise `{ldr,str}ex` is used in IPC quite often, but it is so low level that has nothing to do with the remoteproc module in Linux kernel.

Comment: @Grissiom  That is correct.  I was proposing a `{ldr,str}ex` as an alternative to remoteproc.  He has a dual core ARM-Cortex and then says he wants Asymmetric Multiprocessing?  For example, [Atomic operations in ARM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894059/atomic-operations-in-arm) has information on *inter-cpu* primatives.  A simple ring buffer can be used for some IPC schemes.

Answer (score 2):

I come across the same issue as well. I found some additional resources:

1. Doc in the kernel tree as always:

   https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/remoteproc.txt
2. OMAP wiki that gives the overview of the design:

   http://omappedia.org/wiki/Design_Overview_-_RPMsg

BTW. Thanks for the lwn link. That's quite helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Since Xilinx' Zynq SoC also includes 2 ARM Cortex-A9 cores, they have published an application note in which they make a Linux Kernel communicate with a FreeRTOS system via remoteproc/rpmsg. You can find the document here: [PDF](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/petalinux2013_04/ug978-petalinux-zynq-amp.pdf)

Although the document is quite specific, you might be able to pull out some information. You can download the sources here: [Sign in to Download File](https://secure.xilinx.com/webreg/register.do?group=dlc&htmlfile=&emailFile=&cancellink=&eFrom=&eSubject=&version=2013.10&akdm=0&filename=Xilinx-ZC702-AMP-v2013.10-final.bsp) (a Xilinx account is required). The *.bsp file can be renamed to *.tar.gz which can then be extracted.

If you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask.